# Parsing a Graph To Convert It Into Adjacency Lists And CSR And Then Make Connection Queries Using Bidirectional BFS

Tags: java, parsing, graph, breadth-first-search

I was assigned an university project where I had to parse directed graph files coming from [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/) and then convert them into CSR (Compressed Sparse Row) format. Then the client must have the ability to perform connection queries between any 2 vertices by using Bidirectional BFS.

Here is my implementation:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InputInterface input = null;
        switch (args.length)
        {
            case 1:
                input = new KeyboardHandler();
                break;
            case 3:
                if(args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("-f"))
                    input = new QueryFileHandler(args[2]);
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Usage: program <graphPath> [-f <queriesFile> ] ");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Usage: program <graphPath> [-f <queriesFile> ] ");
                System.exit(1);
                break;

        }

        try
        {
            AdjacencyListGraph s = new AdjacencyListGraph(args[0]);
            CSRGraph normalCSR = new CSRGraph(s,GraphType.NORMAL);
            CSRGraph invertedCSR = new CSRGraph(s,GraphType.INVERTED);

            BidirectionalBFS bfs = new BidirectionalBFS(normalCSR,invertedCSR);

            input.processQueries(bfs);
        }
        catch(AdjacencyListGraphNotCompletedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "\nTerminating application...");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        catch(CSRGraphNotCompletedException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "\nTerminating application...");
            System.exit(3);
        }

    }
}
```

**AdjacencyListGraph.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class AdjacencyListGraph
{
    private final HashMap<Long, LinkedList<Long>> normalGraph = new HashMap<>();
    private final HashMap<Long, LinkedList<Long>> invertedGraph = new HashMap<>();
    private int totalEdges;

    //Constructor
    public AdjacencyListGraph(String path) throws AdjacencyListGraphNotCompletedException
    {
        System.out.println("Parsing file " + path);
        long tStart = System.nanoTime();
        try
        {
            File file = new File(path);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");

            int lineCounter = 0;
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lineCounter++;

                if (line.charAt(0) != '#') //Discarding any comments
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Tokenize the line
                        final String[] tokens = pattern.split(line);
                        final long source = Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);
                        final long target = Long.parseLong(tokens[1]);

                        //Add the edge to the 2 Maps
                        addTargetToSource(normalGraph,source,target);
                        addTargetToSource(invertedGraph,target,source);

                        this.totalEdges++;
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException ex)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error at line " + lineCounter + " : Could not parse. String was: " + line + ". Skipping line ");
                    }
                }
            }
            br.close();
            long tEnd = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Loaded " + totalEdges + " edges in " + Duration.ofNanos(tEnd - tStart).toMillis() + "ms");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw new AdjacencyListGraphNotCompletedException("Invalid file path given.");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw new AdjacencyListGraphNotCompletedException("I/0 error occurred.");
        }
    }

    //Getters
    public HashMap<Long, LinkedList<Long>> getNormalGraph()
    {
        return this.normalGraph;
    }
    public HashMap<Long, LinkedList<Long>> getInvertedGraph()
    {
        return invertedGraph;
    }
    public int getTotalEdges()
    {
        return this.totalEdges;
    }

    private void addTargetToSource(HashMap<Long, LinkedList<Long>> map, Long source, Long target)
    {
        map.putIfAbsent(source, new LinkedList<>());
        map.get(source).add(target);
    }
}
```

**AdjacencyListGraphNotCompletedException.java**

```
public class AdjacencyListGraphNotCompletedException extends Exception
{
    public AdjacencyListGraphNotCompletedException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**CSRGraph.java**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

enum GraphType
{
    NORMAL("Normal"),
    INVERTED("Inverted");

    final String name;

    GraphType(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class CSRGraph
{
    private HashMap<Long, Integer> idMap ;
    private int[] IA;
    private long[] JA;

    public CSRGraph(AdjacencyListGraph graph, GraphType type) throws CSRGraphNotCompletedException
    {
        long tStart = System.nanoTime();

        HashMap<Long, LinkedList<Long>> graphMap;

        switch (type)
        {
            case NORMAL:
                graphMap = graph.getNormalGraph();
                break;
            case INVERTED:
                graphMap = graph.getInvertedGraph();
                break;
            default:
                throw new CSRGraphNotCompletedException("Implementation error.");
        }

        if(graphMap.isEmpty())
            throw new CSRGraphNotCompletedException("Error in the creation of CSR: No edges exist.");

        this.idMap = new HashMap<>(graphMap.size());

        this.IA = new int[graphMap.size()+1];
        this.IA[0] = 0;

        this.JA = new long[graph.getTotalEdges()];

        int IA_Index = 0;
        int JA_Index = 0;
        //Iterate through every HashMap entry
        for(Map.Entry<Long, LinkedList<Long>> entry : graphMap.entrySet())
        {
            long key = entry.getKey();
            LinkedList<Long> values = entry.getValue();

            for (long target : values)
                this.JA[JA_Index++] = target;

            this.idMap.put(key, IA_Index);
            this.IA[IA_Index + 1] = IA[IA_Index] + values.size();

            IA_Index++;
        }

        long tEnd = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(type.name + " graph conversion to CSR took " + Duration.ofNanos(tEnd - tStart).toMillis() + "ms");
    }

    public LinkedList<Long> getNeighbors(long id)
    {
        LinkedList<Long> children = new LinkedList<>();

        if(!idMap.containsKey(id))
            return children;

        int id_Index = idMap.get(id);

        long [] children_arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(JA,IA[id_Index],IA[id_Index+1]);

        for(long target : children_arr)
            children.add(target);

        return children;
    }

    public boolean vertexExists(long id)
    {
        return idMap.containsKey(id);
    }
}
```

**CSRGraphNotCompletedException.java**

```
public class CSRGraphNotCompletedException extends Exception
{
    public CSRGraphNotCompletedException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**BidirectionalBFS.java**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class BidirectionalBFS
{
    private final CSRGraph normalGraph;
    private final CSRGraph invertedGraph;

    public BidirectionalBFS(CSRGraph normalGraph, CSRGraph invertedGraph)
    {
        this.normalGraph = normalGraph;
        this.invertedGraph = invertedGraph;
    }

    public BFSResult connectionQuery(VertexPair query)
    {
        long tStart = System.nanoTime();

        long source = query.getSourceNode();
        long target = query.getTargetNode();


        /*We then check if the source and target nodes even exist in the graph.
          We earn a lot of time if we skip doomed BFS queries.
         */
        boolean source_exists = normalGraph.vertexExists(source);
        boolean target_exists = invertedGraph.vertexExists(target);

        if(!source_exists || !target_exists)
            return new BFSResult(source,source_exists,target,target_exists,false,null,Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime() - tStart));
        else if(source == target)
            return new BFSResult(source, true, target, true,true, 0, Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime() - tStart));


        LinkedList<Long> queueNormal = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Long> queueInverted = new LinkedList<>();

        HashMap<Long,Integer> nodeInfoNormal = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Long,Integer> nodeInfoInverted = new HashMap<>();

        nodeInfoNormal.put(source,0);
        nodeInfoInverted.put(target,0);

        queueNormal.add(source);
        queueInverted.add(target);

        while (!queueNormal.isEmpty() || !queueInverted.isEmpty())
        {
            Intersection intersection;
            if ((intersection = graphBFS(normalGraph,queueNormal, nodeInfoNormal, nodeInfoInverted)).intersectionExists() ||
                (intersection = graphBFS(invertedGraph,queueInverted, nodeInfoInverted, nodeInfoNormal)).intersectionExists())
            {
               int normalDistance = nodeInfoNormal.get(intersection.getIntersectNode());
               int invertedDistance = nodeInfoInverted.get(intersection.getIntersectNode());

               int totalDistance = normalDistance + invertedDistance;

               return new BFSResult(source, true, target, true, true, totalDistance, Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime() - tStart));
            }
        }
        return new BFSResult(source,true,target,true,false,null,Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime() - tStart));
    }

    private Intersection graphBFS(CSRGraph graph,
                                  LinkedList<Long> queue,
                                  HashMap<Long,Integer> nodeInfoThisGraph,
                                  HashMap<Long,Integer> nodeInfoOtherGraph)
    {
        if (!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            long current_node = queue.remove();

            LinkedList<Long> adjacentNodes = graph.getNeighbors(current_node);

            while (!adjacentNodes.isEmpty())
            {
                long adjacent = adjacentNodes.poll();

                if (nodeInfoOtherGraph.containsKey(adjacent))
                {
                    nodeInfoThisGraph.put(adjacent,nodeInfoThisGraph.get(current_node)+1);
                    return new Intersection(true,adjacent);
                }
                else if(!nodeInfoThisGraph.containsKey(adjacent))
                {
                    nodeInfoThisGraph.put(adjacent,nodeInfoThisGraph.get(current_node)+1);
                    queue.add(adjacent);
                }
            }
        }
        return new Intersection(false,null);
    }

    public void areConnected(VertexPair query)
    {
        BFSResult res = connectionQuery(query);
        System.out.println(res.toString());
    }
}

final class BFSResult {
    private final long source_id;
    private final boolean source_exists;
    private final long target_id;
    private final boolean target_exists;
    private final boolean areConnected;
    private final Integer distance;
    private final Duration timeElapsed;

    public BFSResult(long source_id, boolean source_exists, long target_id, boolean target_exists, boolean areConnected, Integer distance, Duration timeElapsed) {
        this.source_id = source_id;
        this.source_exists = source_exists;
        this.target_id = target_id;
        this.target_exists = target_exists;
        this.areConnected = areConnected;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.timeElapsed = timeElapsed;
    }

    public long getSource_id()
    {
        return source_id;
    }
    public boolean isSource_exists()
    {
        return source_exists;
    }
    public long getTarget_id()
    {
        return target_id;
    }
    public boolean isTarget_exists()
    {
        return target_exists;
    }
    public boolean isAreConnected()
    {
        return areConnected;
    }
    public Integer getDistance()
    {
        return distance;
    }
    public Duration getTimeElapsed()
    {
        return timeElapsed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BFSResult{" +
                "source_id=" + source_id +
                ", source_exists=" + source_exists +
                ", target_id=" + target_id +
                ", target_exists=" + target_exists +
                ", areConnected=" + areConnected +
                ", distance=" + distance +
                ", timeElapsed=" + timeElapsed.toMillis() + "ms" +
                '}';
    }
}


final class Intersection
{
    private final boolean intersectionExists;
    private final Long intersectNode;

    public Intersection(boolean intersectionExists,Long intersectNode)
    {
        this.intersectionExists = intersectionExists;
        this.intersectNode = intersectNode;
    }

    public boolean intersectionExists()
    {
        return intersectionExists;
    }

    public Long getIntersectNode()
    {
        return intersectNode;
    }
}
```

**InputInterface.java**

```
public interface InputInterface
{
    void processQueries(BidirectionalBFS bfs);
}
```

**KeyboardHandler.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KeyboardHandler implements InputInterface
{
    private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void processQueries(BidirectionalBFS bfs)
    {
        System.out.println("Using keyboard input.");
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Give a node pair (source,target)");
            VertexPair query = new VertexPair(longPositiveZero(),longPositiveZero());
            bfs.areConnected(query);

            System.out.println("Would you like an another query? (Yes/No)");
            String answer = stringEqualsIgnoreCase(new String[]{"Yes","No"});

            if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("No"))
            {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using our software!");
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }
    }

    public long longPositiveZero()
    {
        long value;

        while(true)
        {
            while (!scan.hasNextLong())
            {
                System.out.println("Expected an Integer. Please type again.");
                scan.next();
            }
            value = scan.nextLong();
            if(value >= 0)
                return value;
            else
                System.out.println("Field cannot be negative. Please type again.");
        }

    }

    public String stringEqualsIgnoreCase(String[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            String value = scan.next();
            for(String i : args)
            {
                if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(i))
                    return i;
            }
            System.out.println("Invalid value. Please type again.");
        }
    }
}
```

**QueryFileHandler.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class QueryFileHandler implements InputInterface
{
    private String path;

    public QueryFileHandler(String path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public void processQueries(BidirectionalBFS bfs)
    {
        System.out.println("Using file input mode.");

        LinkedList<VertexPair> queries = null;
        try
        {
            queries = parseQueries();
        }
        catch (QueryFileHandlerException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "\nTerminating application...");
            System.exit(3);
        }

        while(queries.size() != 0)
        {
            VertexPair query = queries.poll();
            bfs.areConnected(query);
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you for using our software!");
    }

    private LinkedList<VertexPair> parseQueries() throws QueryFileHandlerException
    {
        long totalQueries = 0;
        LinkedList<VertexPair> queries = new LinkedList<>();

        System.out.println("Parsing query file " + path);
        long tStart = System.nanoTime();
        try
        {
            File file = new File(path);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");

            int lineCounter = 0;
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lineCounter++;

                if (line.charAt(0) != '#') //Discarding any comments
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Tokenize the line
                        final String[] tokens = pattern.split(line);
                        final long source = Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);
                        final long target = Long.parseLong(tokens[1]);

                        queries.add(new VertexPair(source,target));
                        totalQueries++;

                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException ex)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error at line " + lineCounter + " : Could not parse. String was: " + line + ". Skipping line ");
                    }
                }
            }
            br.close();
            long tEnd = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("Loaded " + totalQueries + " queries in " + Duration.ofNanos(tEnd - tStart).toMillis() + "ms");

            if(totalQueries == 0)
                throw new QueryFileHandlerException("File does not contain any pair of nodes.");

            return queries;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw new QueryFileHandlerException("Invalid file path given.");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw new QueryFileHandlerException("I/0 error occurred.");
        }
    }
```

**QueryFileHandlerException.java**

```
public class QueryFileHandlerException extends Exception
{
    public QueryFileHandlerException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**VertexPair.java**

```
public class VertexPair
{
    private long sourceNode;
    private long targetNode;

    public VertexPair(long sourceNode, long targetNode)
    {
        this.sourceNode = sourceNode;
        this.targetNode = targetNode;
    }

    public long getSourceNode()
    {
        return sourceNode;
    }

    public long getTargetNode()
    {
        return targetNode;
    }
}
```

**Part from a sample file [soc-epinions1.txt](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-Epinions1.html)**

```
# Directed graph (each unordered pair of nodes is saved once): soc-Epinions1.txt 
# Directed Epinions social network
# Nodes: 75879 Edges: 508837
# FromNodeId    ToNodeId
0   4
0   5
0   7
0   8
0   9
0   10
0   11
0   12
0   13
0   14
0   15
0   16
0   17
```

What is your opinion about this implementation ? Please suggest any enhancements that can be made.

Comment: A sample of the data in the file and what the expected return would be, will go a long way toward getting proper answers.

Comment: @tinstaafl edited.